# module overriding in zen cart

Tags: module, zen-cart

I am new to Zen Cart and currently working on a project which has custom template. I am now stuck on override of module file new_products.php !! how to override new_products.php ? I want to change HTML in it. how can I do it ? I have made changes in new_products.php itself. I know it is not right way to do it, but I am confused where do I make changes/override module file ?

Here is the code where I made changes in main new_products.php file

```
while (!$new_products->EOF) {
$products_price = zen_get_products_display_price($new_products->fields['products_id']);
if (!isset($productsInCategory[$new_products->fields['products_id']])) $productsInCategory[$new_products->fields['products_id']] = zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($new_products->fields['master_categories_id']);

$list_box_contents[$row][$col] = array('params' => 'class="centerBoxContentsNew centeredContent back"' . ' ' . 'style="width:' . $col_width . '%;"',
'text' => (($new_products->fields['products_image'] == '' and PRODUCTS_IMAGE_NO_IMAGE_STATUS == 0) ? '' :  '<center><h2>'.$new_products->fields['products_name'].'</h2><a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($new_products->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . $productsInCategory[$new_products->fields['products_id']] . '&products_id=' . $new_products->fields['products_id']) . '">' . zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $new_products->fields['products_image'], $new_products->fields['products_name'], IMAGE_PRODUCT_NEW_WIDTH, IMAGE_PRODUCT_NEW_HEIGHT) . '</a></center>') . '<h3>' . $products_price.'</h3><p>'.$new_products->fields['products_description'].'</p>
    <div class="button black"><a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($new_products->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . $productsInCategory[$new_products->fields['products_id']] . '&products_id=' . $new_products->fields['products_id']) . '">Add To Cart' .'</div>');

$col ++;
if ($col > (SHOW_PRODUCT_INFO_COLUMNS_NEW_PRODUCTS - 1)) {
  $col = 0;
  $row ++;
}
$new_products->MoveNextRandom();}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to modify new_products.php, but first copy

```
includes/modules/new_products.php
```

to

```
includes/modules/YOUR_TEMPLATE/new_products.php
```

(where YOUR_TEMPLATE is the name of your custom template).

Then make changes in the file

```
includes/modules/YOUR_TEMPLATE/new_products.php
```

You can determine your template name by going to admin->tools->template selection.

If you don't know how to create a custom template in Zen Cart, read this: 
http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?180

Comment: I have tried it earlier, but I think may be I have made mistake in module template directory name :)
Thank You

Comment: ah ok.  Added some more clarifying comments about templates to my answer.